# Exclude element area from scroll listener

Tags: javascript

Created a movable element that opens/closes by click. It stores a list that will scroll.

```
let widget = document.getElementById("widget") // div wrapper
```

Added an event addEventListener("mousewheel") to close my element by scroll:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", (event) => {
    Plugin.prototype.widget.close() // close widget
})
```

It is necessary to achieve the result: the widget is closed everywhere along the scroll, except for the scroll in the widget itself, taking into account all child elements.

The following code defines the active scroll area:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", (event) => {
    if ( event.target !== widget ) { // isn't widget
        Plugin.prototype.widget.close() // close widget
    }
})
```

Is it possible to make a check to determine the element and all its children by scrolling?

Comment: You can use [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to detect whether or not event.target is within your widget.

Comment: @raina77ow How I can use contains? `event.target.contains(widget)` ?